# Flex; recognize email addresses as object in a text field

Tags: apache-flex

I am searching for a way to convert an email address once entered in a textfield as an object like shown in this image on  MS office outlook  ;

[alt text http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/4765/41913045.jpg](http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/4765/41913045.jpg)

the point is that now in outlook as my cursor is positioned just after "user2@gmail.com" if I click backspace I will delete the entire email address, as if it was one object and not simple text entered.

I suppose this is possible in flex? All ideas and suggestions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT is possible; but you'll probably have to create a component for doing so.

I believe [Hillel Coren's AutoComplete component](http://hillelcoren.com/flex-autocomplete/) supports "multiple select" functionality in this manner.  Just check out the demo.  I'm not sure of the customization for that, though.

Comment: thanx @www.Flextras.com once again just what I need.

Comment: Great!  Be sure to select this as the "correct answer" if you it is what you need.